# Problem Dealing w/ Optimization

Tags: calculus, derivatives, optimization

this problem in my Calc one class is really giving me a hard time. Any help would be much appreciated.

Find the number of units that must be produced and sold in order to yield the maximum profit, given the following equations for revenue and cost:

$R(x)= 20x - 0.5x^2$

$C(x)= 7x + 4$

Comment: Profit = Revenue - Cost. Set up a formula for profit in terms of units produced.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Profit is revenue - cost. Write this in terms of R(x) and C(x). Look at the profit function's derivatives and recall the rules you've been given for finding global maximums

Answer (score 1):

Okay! Thank you guys very much.

Here's what I got:

$R'(x)= 20 - x$

$C'(x)= 7$

$R'(x)= C'(x)$

$20 - x= 7$

$x= 13$

Okay thanks. That turned out to be a pretty simple problem. Just another one I over analyze.